# how can get database name in wordpress?

Tags: database

I want to get WordPress database name. I have also try to get database name from $wpdb but failed. When print the $wpdb it give an object array but i don't know how to get database name from object array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the db name using `$wpdb`:

```
global $wpdb;
echo $wpdb->dbname;
```

It will return database name as a string.

Comment: `$wpdb->dbname` is a protected property: you shouldn't read it. Use `DB_NAME ` constant instead, as @chittaranjan suggested.

Comment: @AndreaSciamanna what is wrong using `$wpdb->dbname`? Would you please care to explain? That will be helpful.

Comment: This is wrong answer! To use from `$dbname` you should call if at first by `global $dbname`. Then no need to `wpdb`(it's wrong to use `wpdb`). Just use `$dbname`. But the better approach is `DB_NAME` constant.

Comment: The constant DB_NAME is not always defined - when the HyperDB plugin is in use (replaces WPDB class to support multiple databases), then having a single DB_NAME constant wouldn't make sense

Answer (score 7):

You can also get the database name from the constant `DB_NAME` without going for `$wpdb`.

Comment: This is best answer.

Comment: what scope do you need to be in, or what library or object do you need to load in order for `DB_NAME` to be recognized, and not be an uninitialized constant?

Comment: The constant DB_NAME is not always defined - when the HyperDB plugin is in use (replaces WPDB class to support multiple databases), then having a single DB_NAME constant wouldn't make sense